# Unable to display headers and rows in google sheet through apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to learn and enhance my skills in google apps script. And i am trying to display headers and rows in google sheet through google apps script.

Main Code:

```
function inserted() {

  var url = "https://api.**********************************";
  var api_key = "********************";
  var auth = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(api_key + ":x");
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, { "headers":{ "ApiKey": api_key, "Authorization": auth } } ); 
  var content = res.getContentText(); 

  var gsheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = gsheet.getSheetByName("MAIN");

  const xmlString = content;
  var document = XmlService.parse(xmlString);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var headers = []
  headers.push('id')
  root.getChild("fieldset").getDescendants().filter(dsc => dsc.asElement()).forEach(el => {headers.push(el.getText()) })
  var rows = []
  
  root.getChild("employees").getChildren("employee").forEach(emp => {
    var prov=[]
    prov.push(emp.getAttribute('id').getValue())
    emp.getDescendants().filter(dsc => dsc.asElement()).forEach(el => { prov.push(el.getText())})
    rows.push(prov)
  })
  //return ([headers, ...rows])
  mainSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([headers]);
}
```

**The above code display only id.**

I want to display all the headers and rows as well. I've tried following code as well

```
mainSheet.getRange("id!A1:D4").setValue([headers]); // Error
mainSheet.getRangeList(['A1:D4']).setValue([headers]); // it display only id in the range
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Ths is assuming each row is the same length as required by `setValues()`.

```
var rows = [headers]
// your code inbetween
mainSheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
```